# How to analyze from vmcore by crash why the function accessed a null pointer and caused the OS to crash

Tags: c, assembly, linux-kernel, crash, x86-64

The operating system(RHEL) was accidentally crashed suddenly, after reboot it is back to normal, there is no way to reproduce.

And I am new to both C and assembly language.Because of my lack of ability, I can only analyze that it is line 122 of `jhash.h` that causes `mov 0x5c(%rax),%ecx` to access a null pointer, but I would like to know what the null pointer is and where it comes from?

OS version: `Linux version 3.10.0-1160.15.2.el7.x86_64`
gcc version: `4.8.5 20150623`

backtrace:

```
crash> bt
PID: 0      TASK: ffff885f33b4a100  CPU: 6   COMMAND: "swapper/6"
 #0 [ffff8865dd783640] machine_kexec at ffffffffbae662c4
 #1 [ffff8865dd7836a0] __crash_kexec at ffffffffbaf227a2
 #2 [ffff8865dd783770] crash_kexec at ffffffffbaf22890
 #3 [ffff8865dd783788] oops_end at ffffffffbb58c798
 #4 [ffff8865dd7837b0] no_context at ffffffffbae75d14
 #5 [ffff8865dd783800] __bad_area_nosemaphore at ffffffffbae75fe2
 #6 [ffff8865dd783850] bad_area_nosemaphore at ffffffffbae76104
 #7 [ffff8865dd783860] __do_page_fault at ffffffffbb58f750
 #8 [ffff8865dd7838d0] do_page_fault at ffffffffbb58f975
 #9 [ffff8865dd783900] page_fault at ffffffffbb58b778
    [exception RIP: hash_ip4_test+41]
    RIP: ffffffffc08e5909  RSP: ffff8865dd7839b8  RFLAGS: 00010296
    RAX: 0000000000000000  RBX: ffff88656f363800  RCX: ffff8865dd783aa0
    RDX: ffff8865dd783a10  RSI: ffff8865dd783a0c  RDI: ffff88656f363800
    RBP: ffff8865dd7839f8   R8: 0000000000000000   R9: ffff8865dd783a10
    R10: ffff8865dd783aa0  R11: ffff885e7af65b80  R12: ffff8865dd783a98
    R13: ffff8863c8f22f00  R14: ffff88656f363800  R15: ffff8865dd783a0c
    ORIG_RAX: ffffffffffffffff  CS: 0010  SS: 0018
#10 [ffff8865dd783a00] hash_ip4_kadt at ffffffffc08e4106 [ip_set_hash_ip]
#11 [ffff8865dd783a58] ip_set_test at ffffffffc08ffcc0 [ip_set]
#12 [ffff8865dd783a90] set_match_v4 at ffffffffc09a4dc0 [xt_set]
#13 [ffff8865dd783ae8] ipt_do_table at ffffffffc0545640 [ip_tables]
#14 [ffff8865dd783c38] iptable_mangle_hook at ffffffffc0878043 [iptable_mangle]
#15 [ffff8865dd783c78] nf_iterate at ffffffffbb495a48
#16 [ffff8865dd783cb8] nf_hook_slow at ffffffffbb495b38
#17 [ffff8865dd783cf0] ip_rcv at ffffffffbb4a0559
#18 [ffff8865dd783d60] __netif_receive_skb_core at ffffffffbb455829
#19 [ffff8865dd783dd0] __netif_receive_skb at ffffffffbb455b28
#20 [ffff8865dd783df0] netif_receive_skb_internal at ffffffffbb455bb0
#21 [ffff8865dd783e20] napi_gro_receive at ffffffffbb456838
#22 [ffff8865dd783e48] gro_cell_poll at ffffffffc09ba187 [vxlan]
#23 [ffff8865dd783e78] net_rx_action at ffffffffbb4561cf
#24 [ffff8865dd783ef8] __do_softirq at ffffffffbaea4b35
#25 [ffff8865dd783f68] call_softirq at ffffffffbb5984ec
#26 [ffff8865dd783f80] do_softirq at ffffffffbae2f715
#27 [ffff8865dd783fa0] irq_exit at ffffffffbaea4eb5
#28 [ffff8865dd783fb8] do_IRQ at ffffffffbb599936
--- <IRQ stack> ---
#29 [ffff885f33b5bdf8] ret_from_intr at ffffffffbb58b36a
    [exception RIP: native_safe_halt+11]
    RIP: ffffffffbb589ebb  RSP: ffff885f33b5bea8  RFLAGS: 00000286
    RAX: ffffffffbb589c70  RBX: 006cc0c03aa693c0  RCX: 0100000000000000
    RDX: 0000000000000000  RSI: 0000000000000000  RDI: 0000000000000046
    RBP: ffff885f33b5bea8   R8: 0000000000000000   R9: 0000000000000001
    R10: 0000000000000000  R11: 7fffffffffffffff  R12: 006cc0c03aa693c0
    R13: 0000000000000006  R14: 006cc0c03a0dfd40  R15: 0dd5743fda151c77
    ORIG_RAX: ffffffffffffff73  CS: 0010  SS: 0018
#30 [ffff885f33b5beb0] default_idle at ffffffffbb589c8e
#31 [ffff885f33b5bed0] arch_cpu_idle at ffffffffbae37ca0
#32 [ffff885f33b5bee0] cpu_startup_entry at ffffffffbaf0142a
#33 [ffff885f33b5bf28] start_secondary at ffffffffbae5a827
#34 [ffff885f33b5bf50] start_cpu at ffffffffbae000d5
```

Disassembly:

```
crash> dis -rl ffffffffc08e5909
/usr/src/debug/kernel-3.10.0-1160.15.2.el7/linux-3.10.0-1160.15.2.el7.x86_64/net/netfilter/ipset/ip_set_hash_gen.h: 988
0xffffffffc08e58e0 <hash_ip4_test>:     nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1) [FTRACE NOP]
0xffffffffc08e58e5 <hash_ip4_test+5>:   push   %rbp
0xffffffffc08e58e6 <hash_ip4_test+6>:   mov    %rcx,%r10
0xffffffffc08e58e9 <hash_ip4_test+9>:   mov    %rdx,%r9
0xffffffffc08e58ec <hash_ip4_test+12>:  mov    %rsp,%rbp
0xffffffffc08e58ef <hash_ip4_test+15>:  push   %r15
0xffffffffc08e58f1 <hash_ip4_test+17>:  mov    %rsi,%r15
0xffffffffc08e58f4 <hash_ip4_test+20>:  push   %r14
0xffffffffc08e58f6 <hash_ip4_test+22>:  mov    %rdi,%r14
0xffffffffc08e58f9 <hash_ip4_test+25>:  push   %r13
0xffffffffc08e58fb <hash_ip4_test+27>:  push   %r12
0xffffffffc08e58fd <hash_ip4_test+29>:  push   %rbx
0xffffffffc08e58fe <hash_ip4_test+30>:  sub    $0x18,%rsp
/usr/src/debug/kernel-3.10.0-1160.15.2.el7/linux-3.10.0-1160.15.2.el7.x86_64/net/netfilter/ipset/ip_set_hash_gen.h: 989
0xffffffffc08e5902 <hash_ip4_test+34>:  mov    0x80(%rdi),%rax
/usr/src/debug/kernel-3.10.0-1160.15.2.el7/linux-3.10.0-1160.15.2.el7.x86_64/include/linux/jhash.h: 122
0xffffffffc08e5909 <hash_ip4_test+41>:  mov    0x5c(%rax),%ecx
```

Disassembly:

```
crash>  dis -l hash_ip4_test+41
/usr/src/debug/kernel-3.10.0-1160.15.2.el7/linux-3.10.0-1160.15.2.el7.x86_64/include/linux/jhash.h: 122
0xffffffffc08e5909 <hash_ip4_test+41>:  mov    0x5c(%rax),%ecx
```

Lines 57-132 of the /usr/src/debug/kernel-3.10.0-1160.15.2.el7/linux-3.10.0-1160.15.2.el7.x86_64/include/linux/jhash.h file:

```c
...
     57 /* An arbitrary initial parameter */
     58 #define JHASH_INITVAL           0xdeadbeef
     59 
     60 /* jhash - hash an arbitrary key
     61  * @k: sequence of bytes as key
     62  * @length: the length of the key
     63  * @initval: the previous hash, or an arbitray value
     64  *
     65  * The generic version, hashes an arbitrary sequence of bytes.
     66  * No alignment or length assumptions are made about the input key.
     67  *
     68  * Returns the hash value of the key. The result depends on endianness.
     69  */
     70 static inline u32 jhash(const void *key, u32 length, u32 initval)
     71 {
     72         u32 a, b, c;
     73         const u8 *k = key;
     74 
     75         /* Set up the internal state */
     76         a = b = c = JHASH_INITVAL + length + initval;
     77 
     78         /* All but the last block: affect some 32 bits of (a,b,c) */
     79         while (length > 12) {
     80                 a += __get_unaligned_cpu32(k);
     81                 b += __get_unaligned_cpu32(k + 4);
     82                 c += __get_unaligned_cpu32(k + 8);
     83                 __jhash_mix(a, b, c);
     84                 length -= 12;
     85                 k += 12;
     86         }
     87         /* Last block: affect all 32 bits of (c) */
     88         /* All the case statements fall through */
     89         switch (length) {
     90         case 12: c += (u32)k[11]<<24;
     91         case 11: c += (u32)k[10]<<16;
     92         case 10: c += (u32)k[9]<<8;
     93         case 9:  c += k[8];
     94         case 8:  b += (u32)k[7]<<24;
     95         case 7:  b += (u32)k[6]<<16;
     96         case 6:  b += (u32)k[5]<<8;
     97         case 5:  b += k[4];
     98         case 4:  a += (u32)k[3]<<24;
     99         case 3:  a += (u32)k[2]<<16;
    100         case 2:  a += (u32)k[1]<<8;
    101         case 1:  a += k[0];
    102                  __jhash_final(a, b, c);
    103         case 0: /* Nothing left to add */
    104                 break;
    105         }
    106 
    107         return c;
    108 }
    109 
    110 /* jhash2 - hash an array of u32's
    111  * @k: the key which must be an array of u32's
    112  * @length: the number of u32's in the key
    113  * @initval: the previous hash, or an arbitray value
    114  *
    115  * Returns the hash value of the key.
    116  */
    117 static inline u32 jhash2(const u32 *k, u32 length, u32 initval)
    118 {
    119         u32 a, b, c;
    120 
    121         /* Set up the internal state */
    122         a = b = c = JHASH_INITVAL + (length<<2) + initval;
    123 
    124         /* Handle most of the key */
    125         while (length > 3) {
    126                 a += k[0];
    127                 b += k[1];
    128                 c += k[2];
    129                 __jhash_mix(a, b, c);
    130                 length -= 3;
    131                 k += 3;
    132         }
...
```

vmcore-dmesg.txt:

```
...

[30611156.397794] BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at 000000000000005c
[30611156.397866] IP: [<ffffffffc08e5909>] hash_ip4_test+0x29/0x120 [ip_set_hash_ip]
[30611156.397894] PGD 53dac5067 PUD 79d27a067 PMD 0 
[30611156.397913] Oops: 0000 [#1] SMP 
[30611156.397927] Modules linked in: ext4 mbcache jbd2 binfmt_misc veth vxlan ip6_udp_tunnel ipt_REJECT udp_tunnel nf_reject_ipv4 xt_set ip_set_hash_ip ip_set_hash_net ip_set nf_conntrack_netlink xt_addrtype xt_nat xt_statistic ipt_MASQUERADE nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4 xt_mark xt_comment xt_conntrack iptable_filter iptable_nat nf_nat_ipv4 nf_nat iptable_mangle nf_tables nfnetlink nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 ip_vs_sh ip_vs_wrr ip_vs_rr ip_vs nf_conntrack overlay(T) vsock_diag tcp_diag udp_diag inet_diag unix_diag af_packet_diag netlink_diag vmw_vsock_vmci_transport vsock sunrpc ppdev iosf_mbi crc32_pclmul vmw_balloon ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd joydev pcspkr sg vmw_vmci i2c_piix4 parport_pc parport ip_tables xfs libcrc32c sr_mod cdrom ata_generic pata_acpi
[30611156.398212]  vmwgfx drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sd_mod sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops crc_t10dif crct10dif_generic ttm ahci drm ata_piix libahci crct10dif_pclmul crct10dif_common crc32c_intel libata nfit libnvdimm serio_raw vmxnet3 vmw_pvscsi drm_panel_orientation_quirks dm_mirror dm_region_hash dm_log dm_mod fuse
[30611156.398321] CPU: 6 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/6 Kdump: loaded Tainted: G               ------------ T 3.10.0-1160.15.2.el7.x86_64 #1
[30611156.398351] Hardware name: VMware, Inc. VMware Virtual Platform/440BX Desktop Reference Platform, BIOS 6.00 11/12/2020
[30611156.398379] task: ffff885f33b4a100 ti: ffff885f33b58000 task.ti: ffff885f33b58000
[30611156.398401] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffffc08e5909>]  [<ffffffffc08e5909>] hash_ip4_test+0x29/0x120 [ip_set_hash_ip]
[30611156.398429] RSP: 0018:ffff8865dd7839b8  EFLAGS: 00010296
[30611156.398446] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff88656f363800 RCX: ffff8865dd783aa0
[30611156.398467] RDX: ffff8865dd783a10 RSI: ffff8865dd783a0c RDI: ffff88656f363800
[30611156.398487] RBP: ffff8865dd7839f8 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: ffff8865dd783a10
[30611156.398507] R10: ffff8865dd783aa0 R11: ffff885e7af65b80 R12: ffff8865dd783a98
[30611156.398533] R13: ffff8863c8f22f00 R14: ffff88656f363800 R15: ffff8865dd783a0c
[30611156.398554] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff8865dd780000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[30611156.398576] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[30611156.398593] CR2: 000000000000005c CR3: 000000072c816000 CR4: 00000000007607e0
[30611156.398643] PKRU: 00000000
[30611156.398653] Call Trace:
[30611156.398664]  <IRQ> 
[30611156.398678]  [<ffffffffc0942190>] ? hash_net_create+0x410/0x410 [ip_set_hash_net]
[30611156.398702]  [<ffffffffc08e4106>] hash_ip4_kadt+0xb6/0xf0 [ip_set_hash_ip]
[30611156.398725]  [<ffffffffc08ffcc0>] ip_set_test+0xb0/0x1b0 [ip_set]
[30611156.398744]  [<ffffffffc09a4dc0>] set_match_v4+0xa0/0xe0 [xt_set]
[30611156.398769]  [<ffffffffc0545640>] ipt_do_table+0x280/0x740 [ip_tables]
[30611156.398819]  [<ffffffffc07e7cc8>] ? tcp_packet+0x3b8/0xa60 [nf_conntrack]
[30611156.398851]  [<ffffffffbaea3fb7>] ? local_bh_enable+0x17/0x20
[30611156.398871]  [<ffffffffc0878043>] iptable_mangle_hook+0x43/0x130 [iptable_mangle]
[30611156.398897]  [<ffffffffbb495a48>] nf_iterate+0x98/0xe0
[30611156.398913]  [<ffffffffbb495b38>] nf_hook_slow+0xa8/0x110
[30611156.398929]  [<ffffffffbb4a0559>] ip_rcv+0x339/0x420
[30611156.398945]  [<ffffffffbb49fa80>] ? inet_del_offload+0x40/0x40
[30611156.398964]  [<ffffffffbb455829>] __netif_receive_skb_core+0x729/0xa10
[30611156.398985]  [<ffffffffbb4ccd00>] ? tcp4_gro_receive+0x40/0x1a0
[30611156.399004]  [<ffffffffbaf07b1f>] ? __getnstimeofday64+0x3f/0xd0
[30611156.399022]  [<ffffffffbb455b28>] __netif_receive_skb+0x18/0x60
[30611156.399040]  [<ffffffffbb455bb0>] netif_receive_skb_internal+0x40/0xc0
[30611156.399826]  [<ffffffffbb456838>] napi_gro_receive+0xd8/0x100
[30611156.400612]  [<ffffffffc09ba187>] gro_cell_poll+0x57/0x80 [vxlan]
[30611156.401487]  [<ffffffffbb4561cf>] net_rx_action+0x26f/0x390
[30611156.402226]  [<ffffffffbaea4b35>] __do_softirq+0xf5/0x280
[30611156.402981]  [<ffffffffbb5984ec>] call_softirq+0x1c/0x30
[30611156.403710]  [<ffffffffbae2f715>] do_softirq+0x65/0xa0
[30611156.404404]  [<ffffffffbaea4eb5>] irq_exit+0x105/0x110
[30611156.405260]  [<ffffffffbb599936>] do_IRQ+0x56/0xf0
[30611156.405968]  [<ffffffffbb58b36a>] common_interrupt+0x16a/0x16a
[30611156.406645]  <EOI> 
[30611156.406656]  [<ffffffffbb589c70>] ? __cpuidle_text_start+0x8/0x8
[30611156.407913]  [<ffffffffbb589ebb>] ? native_safe_halt+0xb/0x20
[30611156.408499]  [<ffffffffbb589c8e>] default_idle+0x1e/0xc0
[30611156.409068]  [<ffffffffbae37ca0>] arch_cpu_idle+0x20/0xc0
[30611156.409604]  [<ffffffffbaf0142a>] cpu_startup_entry+0x14a/0x1e0
[30611156.410112]  [<ffffffffbae5a827>] start_secondary+0x1f7/0x270
[30611156.410819]  [<ffffffffbae000d5>] start_cpu+0x5/0x14
[30611156.411325] Code: ff 90 0f 1f 44 00 00 55 49 89 ca 49 89 d1 48 89 e5 41 57 49 89 f7 41 56 49 89 fe 41 55 41 54 53 48 83 ec 18 48 8b 87 80 00 00 00 <8b> 48 5c 48 8b 30 41 8b 07 81 e9 0d 41 52 21 89 ca 01 c8 c1 ca 
[30611156.412403] RIP  [<ffffffffc08e5909>] hash_ip4_test+0x29/0x120 [ip_set_hash_ip]
[30611156.412911]  RSP <ffff8865dd7839b8>
[30611156.413496] CR2: 000000000000005c
```

file `net/netfilter/ipset/ip_set_hash_gen.h`:

```
...
    986 mtype_test(struct ip_set *set, void *value, const struct ip_set_ext *ext,
    987            struct ip_set_ext *mext, u32 flags)
    988 {
    989         struct htype *h = set->data;
    990         struct htable *t;
    991         struct mtype_elem *d = value;
    992         struct hbucket *n;
    993         struct mtype_elem *data;
    994         int i, ret = 0;
    995         u32 key, multi = 0;
    996 
    997         t = rcu_dereference_bh(h->table);
    998 #ifdef IP_SET_HASH_WITH_NETS
    999         /* If we test an IP address and not a network address,
   1000          * try all possible network sizes
   1001          */
...
```

Based on peter's suggestion, I added some information, I wonder if
can be infer that `set->data` is the null pointer?
`ip_set` is the first argument of the `mtype_test` function.

```
crash> struct -o ip_set
struct ip_set {
   [0x0] char name[32];
  [0x20] spinlock_t lock;
  [0x24] u32 ref;
  [0x28] u32 ref_netlink;
  [0x30] struct ip_set_type *type;
  [0x38] const struct ip_set_type_variant *variant;
  [0x40] u8 family;
  [0x41] u8 revision;
  [0x42] u8 extensions;
  [0x43] u8 flags;
  [0x44] u32 timeout;
  [0x48] u32 elements;
  [0x50] size_t ext_size;
  [0x58] size_t dsize;
  [0x60] size_t offset[4];
  [0x80] void *data;
}
SIZE: 0x88
crash> struct ip_set ffff88656f363800
struct ip_set {
  name = "\200\060\066oe\210\377\377T-NODE-IP-V4-tmp\000\000\000\000\000\000\000", 
  lock = {
    {
      rlock = {
        raw_lock = {
          val = {
            counter = 0x0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }, 
  ref = 0x0, 
  ref_netlink = 0x0, 
  type = 0xffffffffc08ea380 <hash_ip_type>, 
  variant = 0xffffffffc08e9480 <hash_ip4_variant>, 
  family = 0x2, 
  revision = 0x4, 
  extensions = 0x1, 
  flags = 0x0, 
  timeout = 0x0, 
  elements = 0x20, 
  ext_size = 0xba0, 
  dsize = 0x10, 
  offset = {0x0, 0x8, 0x0, 0x0}, 
  data = 0x0
}
crash>
```

Comment: The null pointer (RAX = 0) came from `mov    0x80(%rdi),%rax`, loading a pointer from `hash_ip4_test`'s first arg.  It's first arg (in RDI) is apparently a pointer to an array or struct, and it loads 8 bytes from an offset of +128 bytes relative to that pointer.  It then treats those 8 bytes as another pointer, dereferencing it with a 4-byte load: `mov    0x5c(%rax),%ecx`.  I'm not familiar with the `hash_ip4_test` function and don't see C source for it in your code blocks.  The faulting instruction itself was attributed to a function inlined into it, from `jhash2()`.

Comment: I am very ashamed of my limited knowledge, but still hope you can help explain a little more clearly.
I can merely understand:
`mov 0x80(%rdi),%rax`
is to move the value of %rdi register offset by 128 bits to %rax.

Also, there is no source code for the hash_ip4_test function in the entire src kernel file, so I don't know how it came to be.
@Peter Cordes

Comment: Debug info says that first load came from `net/netfilter/ipset/ip_set_hash_gen.h` line 989, the same file as the function prologue, so presumably you'd find a function definition there.  Note that it's not just moving the *value* of RDI, it's dereferencing the *address* `%rdi+0x80`.  So the initial function arg could be `int32_t **` since there are two loads to eventually get to a 4-byte object.  But more it's actually a pointer to a struct, with an `int32_t *` struct member.  Probably with more typedefs, and clearly at least one wrapper function, `jhash2()`.

Comment: Presumably this asm is for `mtype_test()` inlined into something.  Its first arg has type `struct ip_set *set`.   https://github.com/kernelim/linux/blob/4936bfb9e6a00e5fdd35f0659949a295863b8a93/net/netfilter/ipset/ip_set_hash_gen.h#L984 (a CentOS clone of RHEL kernel source),  The opening `{` of the function is on line 988 of that file, so that fits with the debug info.  And the `mov 0x80(%rdi),%rax` load of a pointer is `struct htype *h = set->data;`  That's the NULL pointer, and I'm guessing the faulting dereferenced of it is `t = rcu_dereference_bh(h->table);`

Comment: After reading your answer, maybe I'm not the right person to ask these kinds of questions, because I barely understand what you're talking about. My background is in daily maintenance of Linux OS, but code development related only shell and python experience. Do you have a recommended book or website where I can learn how to analyze vmcore files (not that simple command of the crash tool), I may need to learn from the basics, do I have to be familiar with C and assembly language?

Also, is there a direct and simple reason about the cause of this crash? @Peter Cordes

Comment: If you want to debug a kernel written in C, yeah you need to be familiar with C!  If you want to debug a crash work backward from the faulting asm instruction to something in the C, yeah you need to be familiar with at least the basics of asm and how it corresponds to C source code, and how compilers inline functions and optimize code.  [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116) is a good place to start if you want to get into that, especially Matt Godbolt's talk.

Comment: In your case, I think `mtype_test(struct ip_set *set, etc)` is getting called with `set->data == NULL`.  I have no idea why or what might have led to this.  It's generally not expected that people who aren't kernel devs will be able to do any real debugging on kernel crash dumps, just that they can send them in for kernel devs to have a look at.

Comment: Is there a way to prove `set->data == NULL` in the crash tool? For example, the `crash> struct ip_set ffff88656f363800` command, `ffff88656f363800 `is the RDI value  @Peter Cordes

Comment: I'm not familiar with the crash tool you're talking about, but yes, RDI holds the `set` pointer, and your `struct` command which dumped the members of that struct did indeed show `data = 0x0`.  Like on most C implementations, `0` is the object-representation of a null pointer.  (fun fact: The C standard doesn't require that.)  We'd already confirmed from the RAX register value in the crash dump that we'd loaded a null pointer from your struct.  This confirms that offset `0x80(%rdi)` was indeed the right offset for the member named `data`, and that it's `0x0` in memory.

Comment: Through your detailed analysis, we should be able to find the null pointer, if you want, you can answer the analysis process in the form of "answer", I will adopt, so that it can also help others to see the answer.
Unfortunately, I can't analyze why data is `0x0`. I guess it should be very, very difficult to analyze this. @Peter Cordes